# dplyr: create column with list's objects' names

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have two data frames, `df1_09` and `df1_10`, that I put together in a list, `list_of_df`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1_09 <- data.frame(
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  first_column = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  second_column = c(5, 6, 7, 8)
)

df1_10 <- data.frame(
  index = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  first_column = c(4, 2, 3, 1),
  second_column = c(8, 6, 7, 5)
)

list_of_df <- list(df1_09, df1_10)
```

Now I create a function that takes in one of the original data frames, `df1_09`, groups the values according to the `index` variable, and calculates the means for each column. The function also creates an additional column called `type` with the name of the data frame.

```r
output_mean <- function(subset, name) {
  subset %>%
    group_by(index) %>%
    summarize(across(c(first_column, second_column), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    mutate(type = name) %>%
    print()
}

output_mean(df1_09, "df1_09")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type  
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1     1          1.5           5.5 df1_09
#> 2     2          3.5           7.5 df1_09
```

Now what I would like to do, is to *loop* through the list `list_of_df` and get the same result. I have tried the following:

```r
for (i in list_of_df) {
 output_mean(i, "i")
}
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type 
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1          1.5           5.5 i    
#> 2     2          3.5           7.5 i    
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   index first_column second_column type 
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1            3             7 i    
#> 2     2            2             6 i
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get to the names of each object in the list. Have the names being deleted with the creation of the list?

<sup>Created on 2021-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a named `list`, loop over the `names` of the `list`, extract the `list` element with `[[` while passing the name argument as `i`

```
list_of_df <- dplyr::lst(df1_09, df1_10)
for (i in names(list_of_df)) {
   output_mean(list_of_df[[i]], i)
  }
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  index first_column second_column type  
#* <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr> 
#1     1          1.5           5.5 df1_09
#2     2          3.5           7.5 df1_09
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  index first_column second_column type  
#* <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr> 
#1     1            3             7 df1_10
#2     2            2             6 df1_10
```